# Run Excel Solver using Office Scripts (not VBA)

Tags: excel, office-scripts, excel-solver

I need to automate a simple pipeline which runs the Excel Solver.  I'd like to use Office Scripts (TypeScript https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/overview?view=office-scripts).  I've written a VBA script which works, but would rather use Office Script because it is a more robust language, and can be more easily integrated into cloud-based pipelines.

Example VBA script:

```
' Initialize inputs
Range("$A$1:$A$3").Value = 0

' Run solver
SolverSolve
```

Desired Office Scripts

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

    // Initialize inputs
    let currentWorksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    currentWorksheet.getRange("$H$16:$H$24").setValue(0);

    // Run solver
    <<Insert Office Script code here>>
}
```

I don't see the Solver in the ExcelScript API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript?view=office-scripts.  Am I missing something, or is there any other way to get the Solver to run using Office Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put simply, the answer to your question is **no**, you cannot access solver via Office Scripts or any other web based technology supported by Excel.

See the below document for confirmation.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040#OfficeVersion=Web